# How do I find the jsp file which runs first when starting a spring project via web.xml?

Tags: eclipse, spring, jsp

Here's the web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<web-app id="tejrat" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>tejrat-ola</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!--
    Insure that all pages are delivered using UTF-8 character encoding
    -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <!-- CharacterEncodingFilter Filter Mapping -->
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <!-- UrlRewriteFilter -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>logLevel</param-name>
            <param-value>WARN</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
        <param-value>messages</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrListener</listener-class>
    </listener>



    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>tejrat</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>tejrat</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.form</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>tejrat</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.list</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>tejrat</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/home.list</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>tejrat</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/search.list</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>tejrat</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>tejrat</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.view</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>


        <servlet-class>org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet</servlet-class>

        <!--
        <servlet-class>org.directwebremoting.spring.DwrSpringServlet</servlet-class>
        -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>fileUploadMaxBytes</param-name>
            <param-value>5242880</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>allowScriptTagRemoting</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>activeReverseAjaxEnabled</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>scriptCompressed</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>initApplicationScopeCreatorsAtStartup</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <!-- WARNING: allowing JSON-RPC connections bypasses much of the security
        protection that DWR gives you. Take this out if security is important -->
        <init-param>
          <param-name>jsonRpcEnabled</param-name>
          <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <!-- WARNING: allowing JSONP connections bypasses much of the security
        protection that DWR gives you. Take this out if security is important -->
        <init-param>
          <param-name>jsonpEnabled</param-name>
          <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <!-- data: URLs are good for small images, but are slower, and could OOM for
        larger images. Leave this out (or keep 'false') for anything but small images -->
        <init-param>
          <param-name>preferDataUrlSchema</param-name>
          <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/dwr/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>StickyCaptcha</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>nl.captcha.servlet.StickyCaptchaServlet</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>width</param-name>
            <param-value>250</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>height</param-name>
            <param-value>75</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>StickyCaptcha</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/stickyImg</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/jsp/exceptions/404.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/jsp/exceptions/error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>home.list</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

there are 5 other xml files aswell

```
backup-web.xml
dwr.xml
tejrat-servlet.xml
tiles.xml
urlrewrite.xml
```

is it possible that I have to look at these files to figure out this problem?
I'm not sure if these are default spring files or the preveous programmer made these.

Answer (score 0):

At the ene of the web.xml file there is welcome-file-list section, there you have home.list, Now if you look above on the same file that URL is mapped to the tejrat ser let, so take a look into that XML file to see to which controller your request is being forwarded.

Comment: will the controller lead me to a particular jsp file?

Comment: The whole point of a controller is to take the request and direct it to a particular jsp file. You need to take a look at the controller to figure it out. Can you paste code here?